# getElementsByTagName returns 2 times more elements than actually exists

Tags: java, xml-parsing, getelementsbyname

I have parsing XML documents with Java 1.7. When I run the function `document.getElementByTagName("Product")`, I get a number of 6000, but if I open it with Notepad++, I see only 3000 entries.

I have problem with looping through all elements with the wrong number of entries.

Comment: give a sample xml and a sample code of how you parse it.

Comment: Why is there a problem looping over the returned nodelist?

Comment: Reduce your file to just a single product element and see what happens. That's a general strategy: when in doubt, simplify.

Comment: reducing the file to a single product helped a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
The problem was with the XML file. The parent Node had the same name as one of the Children nodes.
for example.

```
> <products>
>          <product>
>                  <name>Blbalbal</name>
>                  <size>14</size>
>                  <cost>2000 $</cost>
>                  <link>
>                        <product>www.somthing.com</product>
>                  </link>
>          </product>
>          <product>
>                  <name>Product2</name>
>                  <size>123</size>
>                  <cost>2 $</cost>
>                  <link>
>                        <product>www.somthing2.com</product>
>                  </link>
>          </product>
> </products>
```

Thats why it, each entry counted twice